# gnome schedule - mysqldump

Tags: gnome, mysql, gnome-schedule

Does anyone know if you can mysqldump with gnome schedule? I can copy files but it is not letting me do this .

```
mysqldump -uroot -pchicken test > /home/meatuser/Documents/testWork/testCronBackup/test.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I use /etc/anacrontab to run `mysqldump`. I do not have a solution for gnome schedule.

Below is the relevant portion of my /etc/anacrontab file.

```
# Custom Backup jobs
# http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/anacron-examples/
#
1   20  maria_backup      /bin/sh /home/steve/Computer/Shell_Scripts/maria_backup.sh 
1   30  ms_windows_backup /bin/sh /home/steve/Computer/Shell_Scripts/ms_windows_backup.sh
```

Below is a copy of my maria_backup.sh script executed form anacron.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Executed from /etc/anacrontab
# mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

mv -f -u /home/steve/Computer/maria_backup/sfmags_backup.sql /home/steve/Computer/maria_backup/sfmags_backup_old.sql
mysqldump -u'steve' -p'xxxxxx' 'sfmags' > /home/steve/Computer/maria_backup/sfmags_backup.sql

chown -f -R steve:backup /home/steve/Computer/maria_backup
```